# Left curly bracket does not work in brackets editor

Tags: code-editor, adobe-brackets

Anyone have the same problem with Brackets editor? I am on windows 7, right bracket is working fine but left not. I press ALTGR + B and it does not work :/
EDIT: problem solved.Just disabled Emmet and works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [file a bug with the Emmet extension author](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet/issues). I just searched and it doesn't appear they're aware of that issue yet.

If you do file a bug, be sure to specify what keyboard layout you're using - it sounds like this issue is specific to certain keyboard layouts only.

Comment: @Blaja: Do you want to post the bug link here? That way others who run across this question can check up on the status of the issue easily...